# Scheduling cronjobs at specified time

Tags: osx, cron

I have scheduled some jobs in **crontab** which are to be run one by one, at some specific time. My script for crontab is :

```
15 10 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchFF.sh
45 11 * * * /Users/sri/files/BatchGC.sh
15 13 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_FF.sh
45 14 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_GUI_GC.sh
15 16 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_FF.sh
45 17 * * * /Users/sri/files/Batch_Sim_GC.sh
```

These scripts ideally should start at 10:15, 11:45, 13:15, 14:45, and so on.
But the scripts are not starting as expected, rather they start at 10:15, 10:15, 10:16, 10:16, 10:17, 10:17.
These scripts are writing some log files also.

*The scripts are executable, and also have logging support as the script gets completed a report is being generated. This script is calling a java application to run in a browser and log of which is stored in a folder. the folder is being created with the date and time when the process is started, thus, bcz of which I was able to detect the time they started.*

I am running it in Apple McBook Air, with OS X 12.4.0 Darwin

Comment: Are you sure that the script starting at 10:15 is not calling the other scripts? That would explain your problem.

Comment: Which OS is this? Which cron daemon?

Comment: @suspectus: This script is calling one java application to run, even the each script executes through cron if I run one of the script to be run from cron. But if I specify more than 1 script this problem comes

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0, i meant OS X 10.8.4, i dont know how to check for cron version:-(

Comment: Is this verbatim output from `crontab -l`?

Comment: @tripleee: yes.

Comment: Rather than relying on the timestamp of the folders, look in your system log to see when the jobs were actually run. Alternatively, log the current date with `date` to a file.